# Word JS getBookmarkRange invalid argument

Tags: javascript, office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I have a word JS application and want to access bookmarks within a document. Below is my code

```
  const testFunc = async () => {
    Word.run(async (context) => {
      const documentRange = context.document.body.getRange();
      const bookmarks = documentRange.getBookmarks(true);

      console.log('bookmarks', bookmarks);

      const bookmark = context.document.getBookmarkRange('276461');
      console.log('bookmark', bookmark);
    }).catch((error) => console.log('error', error.debugInfo));
  };
```

In this example, when I log bookmarks, I get my bookmarks returned as expected. Within the values array of the bookmarks, I can see my bookmark, `276461`.

When I call `context.document.getBookmarkRange('276461')` however, I get an invalid argument error on the function.

```
code: "InvalidArgument"

errorLocation: "Document.getBookmarkRange"

fullStatements: Array (8)
0 "var root = context.root;"
1 "var body = root.body;"
2 "// Instantiate {body}"
3 "var range = body.getRange();"
4 "// Instantiate {range}"
5 "range.getBookmarks(true, undefined);"
6 "var bookmarkRange = root.getBookmarkRange(\"276461\");"
7 "// Instantiate {bookmarkRange}"
```

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that you must include alphabetical characters in your string, and must not use special characters. Underscores are acceptable. For example

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id=\"1234\" w:name="test"/>
```

As the bookmark name will allow the use of

```
context.document.getBookmarkRange('test');
```

If instead, you do something like

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id=\"1234\" w:name="test:1234"/>
```

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id=\"1234\" w:name="1234"/>
```

or

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id=\"1234\" w:name="test@1234"/>
```

You will get an invalid argument error.

underscores are usable, so

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id=\"1234\" w:name="test_1234"/>
```

is valid